# Current GPS location using ArcGIS in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, arcgis

I understand that

```
mapView.locationDisplay.startDataSource()
```

will position the current location marker in the arcGIS map and the image of the current location marker can be changed by adding a image file named LocationDisplay.png inside the project.

By default, the current location icon is a blue circle icon. This icon is by default enclosed within a circle (that has animation). 
When we enlarge the map to the maximum scale, the enclosed circle around the blue circle icon also increases. 
Changing the icon image is of no help as it changes only the blue circle icon to the image we change but the enclosed circle remains.
Please suggest if there is any option for us to remove that animation around the current location icon.

P.S: I am aware that we can get the current location from coreLocation and can place custom marker. Any other better possibilities are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**accuracySymbol** is the symbol that is used to show the accuracy of the location.

```
mapView.locationDisplay.accuracySymbol = [AGSSimpleFillSymbol simpleFillSymbolWithColor:[UIColor clearColor] outlineColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

This is Objective-C code. (Please convert to swift.)

Comment: In swift, it would be like `let symbol = AGSSimpleFillSymbol.simpleFillSymbol() as! AGSSimpleFillSymbol
        symbol.color = UIColor.clearColor()
        symbol.outline.color = UIColor.clearColor()
        mapView.locationDisplay.accuracySymbol = symbol`. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also track the current location just like the delegate method of apple map provides below

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

And track here

```
- (void)registerArcgisAsObserver {
    [ self.viewEvacuation.locationDisplay addObserver:self
                                    forKeyPath:@"location"
                                       options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew)
                                       context:NULL];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {

    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"location"]  ) {
        NSLog(@"Location updated to %@", [self.mapview.locationDisplay mapLocation]);
    }
}
```